# Using firebase database rules to prevent negative values

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to use firebase database rules to prevent negative values.

```
{
"rules": {
    "products": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth != null",
        ".indexOn": ["subgroup", "group", "visibility"],
        ".validate": "newData.child('quantity').val() >= 0"
    }
}
```

However, using the the simulator to test the rule, I am always seeing write denied on validate rule:

```
".validate": "newData.child('quantity').val() >= 0"
```

I am using:

```
location: /products/-KQ1qLkeI3gefuGSFIL_
```

and

```
{
   "quantity": 0
}
```

I am using an authenticated user.

Any idea whats going on here ?

Thanks.

====
update:

changing rules to the following didn't help:

```
"products": {
        "$product": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth != null",
        ".validate": "newData.child('quantity').val() >= 0",
        ".indexOn": ["subgroup", "group", "visibility"]
      }
    },
```

Also, DB design:

```
DBRoot
    products
        -KQ1nPkLeqiTMzEzhrfW
            description:"Limited Edition"
            quantity: 5
            ...
```

Comment: Can you try writing directly to products instead of /products/-KQ1qLkeI3gefuGSFIL_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validation rules are on `/products`, but you are writing to `/products/[autoid]`. Try modifying your rules like so:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "products": {
       "$pid": {
         ".read": true,
         ".write": "auth != null",
         ".indexOn": ["subgroup", "group", "visibility"],
         ".validate": "newData.child('quantity').val() >= 0"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Simulated Rules]

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. I've edited my answer with a screenshot showing it worked for me. There must be something slightly different about what you are doing.

Comment: Can I see your database design ? @dbburgess

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, @Ahsan. You said you used the simulator to test the rule, I emulated what you were doing exactly, and then modified it so the simulation would pass. I didn't actually run it against a real database, just the simulated rules. They work.

Comment: Aha, I see the issue. The json data I was testing with had quotation marks around the number value for quantity and was assuming its a string! Thanks for your help @dbburgess

Comment: Ah-ha, that would do it! No problem, glad you figured it out!